# How to find max sum value for different user in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 'agentid' in this table. Now I want to find the max sum value of 'resolved' for 'agentid'.And also  if i want to use where condition for specify 'reportyear' and 'reportmonth' then what should i do? i have...

$currentMonth = date('M'); 
 $currentYear = date('Y');

How can I do it in laravel?

[image: image of table]

Comment: It's work's ....but i want to find the maximum value among them .

Comment: you want sum of resolved of each agent id and get the highest one ?

Comment: Yes,,, Highest one with his agent id

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: yes.thanks.it's work's,but if i want to use where condition for specify 'reportyear' and 'reportmonth' then what should i do? i have $currentMonth = date('M');
        $currentYear = date('Y');

Comment: Then mark my answer right. Ok will look for that.

Comment: Marked it . Can you provide me a solution please ?

Comment: ok, edit your question and i will also edit my answer for year and month.

Comment: Edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Also edited my answer , change name of column of month and year to reportmonth and reportyear where ever it have been used.

Comment: you got it mate? Please do not forget to up vote my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work . Can you please check it once more?

Comment: have you changed month and year to reportmonth and reportyear

Comment: yes.....$higest_resolved=DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT agentid,SUM(resolved) as resolved_total,reportyear,reportmonth FROM reports where reportmonth='$currentMonth' GROUP by agentid,reportyear,reportmonth ORDER by resolved_total DESC'));

Comment: your concatenation is not right, you are missing '.' before and after $currentMonth, I have corrected my answer,just copy and execute .

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Dec and reportyear=2018 GROUP by agentid,reportyear,reportmonth ORDER by resolve' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT agentid,SUM(resolved) as resolved_total,reportyear,reportmonth FROM reports where reportmonth=Dec and reportyear=2018 GROUP by agentid,reportyear,reportmonth ORDER by resolved_total DESC)

Comment: sorry for that again edited my answer check again.

Comment: Yah...finally i am satisfied. Thank you a lot for your help and valuable time.

Comment: Glad to help, do not forget to up vote my answer.

Comment: I am a new user. I have not enough reputation to vote .Sorry for that .

Comment: oh its ok then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want sum of resolved of each agent id and get the highest one ? If so then you can do something like this

```
$higest_resolved=DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT agentid,SUM(resolved) 
as resolved_total FROM table_name GROUP by agentid ORDER by resolved_total DESC LIMIT 1'));
```

for adding month and year condition,you can do as

```
$higest_resolved=DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT agentid,SUM(resolved) 
as resolved_total,reportyear,reportmonth FROM table_name where reportmonth="'.$currentMonth.'" and reportyear="'.$currentYear.'" GROUP by agentid,reportyear,reportmonth ORDER by resolved_total DESC'));
```

you can still add limit 1 at end to get only one value.